# BeginThread delphi blocking function

Tags: delphi

if using BeginThread in Delphi XE3 the function is blocked. Why is that?

I have tried to create the minimal version of my problem below. Where 2 buttom can be pressed, if presseing button btn1 the caption of btn1 should change to 'nooo'. if btn2 is pressed btn1 caption change to 'yesss'.

When btn1 is pressed I also start a thread using BeginThread that loops forever.

The problem is then, btn1.Caption := 'nooo'; is never reased since BeginThread blocks. Shouled I reach btn1.Caption := 'nooo';

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    function test() : Integer;
    { Private declarations }
  public

    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.test() : Integer;
begin

    while True do
    begin
      Sleep(Random(1000) * 2);
    end;
    Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  id: LongWord;
begin
  BeginThread(nil, 0, Pointer(test), nil, 0, id);
  btn1.Caption := 'nooo';
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   btn1.Caption := 'yesss';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Use TThread class instead and don`t waste you time !

Comment: Your cast lies to the compiler and you pay the price.

Comment: Debugging tip: Put a breakpoint on the `BeginThread` line. When you reach the breakpoint press `F7` to step into the method. You will step straight into into the `test` method which should be a clue to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `Pointer(test)` *calls* `test()` and then type-casts the result to a `Pointer`. Since `test()` never returns, there's no result to cast, and thus no value to pass to `BeginThread()`. `BeginThread()` itself doesn't block; it never gets called in the first place.

The third argument to `BeginThread()` is not of type `Pointer`; it is of type `TThreadFunc`, which is a standalone (non-member) function that receives one `Pointer` argument and returns an `Integer`. Your `TForm1.test()` method doesn't qualify, because it's not a standalone function.

Make `test()` be a standalone function, and then pass it directly to `BeginThread()` (without any type-casting or `@` operator):

```
function test(param: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  while True do
    Sleep(Random(1000) * 2);
  Result := 0;
end;

var
  id: LongWord;
begin
  BeginThread(nil, 0, test, nil, 0, id);
end;
```

Comment: Otherwise, use the `TThread` class instead, which uses `BeginThread()` internally.